# what is the significance of 'retry' and 'every' config parameters in Dancer2::Plugin::Redis

Tags: perl, redis, dancer

I am using Dancer2::Plugin::Redis plugin to handle the Redis connections.
In order to provide the required configuration parameters, the documentation gives the following [sample](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Redis).

```
plugins:
  Redis:
    # if you use TCP/IP:
    server: "localhost:6379"
    # if you use UNIX/Linux sockets:
    sock: "/path/to/sock"
    # (optional) Redis password used with auth:
    password: "Very secure password 123!"
    # (optional) Reconnect up to 60 seconds (reconnect) every 5000 milliseconds (every):
    reconnect: 60
    every: 5000
    # (optional) Redis connection name (NOT the Redis database ID):
    name: "my_connection_name"
    # (optional) Function called on Redis connect:
    on_connect: "MyDancer2App::redis_on_connect"
    # (optional) Use serialization for storing values other than simple scalars with Redis:
```

How does the `reconnect` and `every` parameters work together?
Is it like connection will be alive for 60 seconds and it refreshes every 5 sec? If so, it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://metacpan.org/pod/Redis#reconnect,-every

> The `reconnect` option enables auto-reconnection mode. If we cannot
>   connect to the Redis server, or if a network write fails, we enter
>   retry mode. We will try a new connection every `every` microseconds (1
>   ms by default), up-to `reconnect` seconds.
>
> Be aware that read errors will always thrown an exception, and will
>   not trigger a retry until the new command is sent.
>
> If we cannot re-establish a connection after `reconnect` seconds, an
>   exception will be thrown.

Comment: so as per my understanding this is like, whenever the connection failed then, retry every ```every``` seconds until ```reconnect``` seconds. is that correct? From the above sample, my application will try 12 times and error out in case of failure.

Comment: That's my understanding from the docs too. Although the Dancer2 perldoc says "every" is the number of millseconds and the Redis module it uses says "every" is the number of microseconds, so you may need to double check what actually happens